# neo4j 4.2 how to copy users/passwords from one instance to other instance?

Tags: neo4j

Please, advice how to copy users/passwords from one neo4j version 4.2 instance to other neo4j instance version 4.2 ?

( In neo4j v.3.5 it was easy ,even without stopping the nodes you can just copy the dbms/auth & dbms/roles files to the other node )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4.X there is system database containing the users & roles that need to be backup-ed and restored to the new location in order user credentials to be transferred , but let me know if there is other easiest option...